# Permissions for reading pdf files

Tags: php, permissions, pdf-generation, tcpdf

I am working with the TCPDF library. I have two machines, one with Debian Testing, and the other is an Ubuntu 15.10. I developed a class for generating pdf reports, but I have a problem, when I tested it in the Debian host, everything works perfect:

1- I created a folder named: "pdf" in `/var/www`
2- Then I did: `sudo chown -R www-data:user /var/www/pdf`
3- Generate the pdf file and I obtain:

```
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data www-data 76113 ene 18 09:53 out.pdf
```

4- The folder has:

```
drwxr-xr-x 2 www-data user    4096 ene 18 09:53 pdf
```

I used:

```
const base_path = '/var/www';
$pdf->Output(self::base_path . '/pdf/out.pdf', 'F');
```

Showing it inside an iFrame:

```
<iframe width="100%" height="500" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="true" src="/var/www/pdf/out.pdf" name="iFrameName" id="iframeID"></iframe>
```

I copied the entire project to the Ubuntu host, but showing the pdf file inside the browser I get this error:

```
Forbidden
You don't have permission to access /var/www/pdf/out.pdf on this server.
```

Altought I have the following file settings:

```
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data www-data 76113 ene 18 12:06 out.pdf
```

And the folder has:

```
drwxrwxr-x 2 www-data ubuntu-user    4096 ene 18 09:53 pdf
```

I suspect the error is inside an apache setting I'm missing on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works.

I had to add:

```
<Directory /var/www/pdf>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

to `apache2.conf`

Answer (score 1):

Change your ifreme to u always skip your DOCUMENT_ROOT path

```
<iframe width="100%" height="500" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="true" src="/pdf/out.pdf" name="iFrameName" id="iframeID"></iframe>
```

Comment: Did not work. The get error answer is: `http://localhost/pdf/out.pdf`but the pdf file is in `/var/www/pdf`.